# How to see the type of a scala variable? For instance a Spark PairRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this line:

```
val data = sc.textFile(filepath).zipWithIndex().map{case (k,v) => (v,k)}
```

I would like to create a function which takes `data` as an argument, however  I need to specify it's type, how do I determine what type this is? I know it's a Pair RDD in Spark but I'm unsure of its literal type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method to obtain the inferred type is to just declare the type, but with a wrong type, for instance:

```
val x: Int = "foo"
```

The compiler will complain that x is a `String` instead of `Int`, so you now that `String` is the inferred type with a statement like:

```
val x = "foo"
```

If you're using an IDE, you will most likely have a built-in feature that allows you to see the inferred type. For instance, IntelliJ shows the type when hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>.

In IntelliJ, this feature is called "Quick Documentation" or "Type Info". Go to Settings -> Keymap to see which shortcuts are configured on your machine for those two features.

Answer (score 2):

The type is `RDD[(Long, String)]`. How to check this:

1. use an IDE like IntelliJ IDEA where you can display the type (I use mouse-hover to display the type info)

[image]

2. Without IDE: use the API docs: s`c.textFile` gives  `RDD[String]`,
   `zipWithIndex` gives you `RDD[(String,Long)]`, then switching tuple
   order (key-value) gives `RDD[(Long, String)]`

EDIT: To unable this in IntelliJ, check this box in Settings:

[image]

Comment: I also use IntelliJ, do you know where to enable this setting? And thanks for the answer!